# Low RPM U-Turn in 4th Gear - Why doesn't it stall?

Tags: manual-transmission, mitsubishi, stall, eclipse

I have a 2002 Mitsubishi Eclipse. It has a manual transmission.

When I first taught my girlfriend how to drive it, after about a week of only driving in a church parking lot, she took it to the streets. This is were I'm confused, somehow she made a u-turn while in 4th gear doing only 5 mph. I was pretty sure she would stall the car, she just learned how to drive it.

She made this u-turn and didn't stall while in 4th gear!

Can anyone answer how that can happen?

The RPM's were very low.  I was sitting right there in the passenger seat.  I saw the gear she was in and the speed, 5 mph.

Comment: I edited your question to only include the mechanical portion for ease of reading.  The question was set to be closed.  Please edit and add anything back in that you feel might be relevant that I deleted.  I think the question should stay open now.

Comment: One of my cars will happily go at 5mph in 6th gear. On the flat. It won't accelerate, but there is enough torque there to drag the car round in idle.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you press clutch pedal you can turn any speed you like using mostly the initial speed of the car. She could regulate how much the clutch is engaged carefully so the engine wont stall.

But this kind of driving will cause clutch to wear more. Because clutch is not engaged fully.

But if that is not what she did, are you otherwise able to drive 5mph straight road with 4th gear in same RPM without clutch pedal pressed at all? (if yes, then you can probably also turn as well)

Maybe you could make a video and post to us :)